# spring batch admin console which pom to generate war file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch-admin

I would like to get the spring batch admin console working on my application server. I've just gone to download it from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/releases.

There are a lot of poms in the project? Which pom is the one I have to run to get the war file for the admin console.

My directory structure looks like this...

spring-batch-admin-manager
spring-batch-admin-parent
spring-batch-admin-resources
spring-batch-admin-sample
spring-batch-admin-integration

thanks

Comment: Neither... Use the one in the main directory that will build everything.

Comment: Actually the "spring-batch-admin-sample" is a WAR project. Maybe that's the one you need?